# How to hide/show numeric IDs from just calling a function (js/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to `hide or show` numeric IDs from just calling a created `function hide_IDs()` or `show_IDs`?

My own created codes is not working
on clicking on the submit button, it should hide the IDs 1 to 4 from  tags, calling the function hide_IDS(1,4)

js and jQuery: hinding from ID to ID.

```
function hide_IDs(from,to){
 var i= parseInt(from);
 var z= parseInt(to);
 while( i <= z ){
  $('#'+i).hide();
  i++;
 }
}
```

HTML: on the submit, calling the function hide_IDS(1,4) = to hide ID from 1 to 4

```
<tr id=1><td>To Character Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="Name"></td></tr>
<tr id=2><td>Coins:</td><td><input type="text" id="Coins"></td></tr>
<tr id=3><td>Security Code</td><td><input type="text" id="SecurityCode"></td></tr>
<tr id=4><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Send Now" onclick="hide_IDs(1,4)"></td></tr>
```

DOES NOT WORK, please help. Advance THANKS.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please see the firebug console.

Comment: You have a typo: `hide_IDs` vs `hide_IDS`

Comment: i can't see anything wrong in ur code. Still, i suggest you to change $('#' + i).hide(); to $("#" + i.toString()).hide();

also using only numeric values as id of elements is bad practice

Comment: Aside from fixing the "onclick" so that you spell the function name correctly, you may need to add `; return false` if that "submit" `<input>` is in a form.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a typo in the code.

Comment: + you have several other mistakes in your html. A working example of your function in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nYj8S/

Comment: sorry I just edited my threads that's why is it wrong. But I change the content of this question. Try to test, it does not work..
I see a person he replied $('tr').slice(i, z).hide();
It is working but I need to see his reply again because I accidentally redo the codes and cannot be undo. Maybe it is sTACKoVERFLOW's replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="submit" value="Send Now" onclick="hide_IDs(1,4)">
```

Change:

```
function hide_IDS(from,to){//Your S is capital here
```

To:

```
function hide_IDs(from,to){
```

Comment: sorry I just edited my threads that's why is it wrong. But I change the content of this question. Try to test, it does not work.. I see a person he replied $('tr').slice(i, z).hide(); It is working but I need to see his reply again because I accidentally redo the codes and cannot be undo. Maybe it is your reply. Please edit it again. Thankss.

Answer (score 0):

You got typo error in function name `hide_IDs`as well as you are passing number `hide_IDs(1,4)` which is not require parseInt.

```
function hide_IDs(from,to){

 while( from <= to ){
  $('#'+from).hide();
  from++;
 }
}
```